# Print all array values in <span> tags with a trailing comma except no comma after the last value

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, tags

I am hacking together a theme for Wordpress and I am using the following code to pull out data from a custom field with several values:

```
$mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('services');
foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<span>$value, </span>";
}
```

I use a comma to separate the results, but I don't want a comma after the last result. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way is with [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
echo('<span>' . implode('</span>, <span>', $mykey_values) . '</span>');
```

Comment: ah yes, I'd forgotten about `implode`! But does that cover the `<span>` tags?

Comment: Yeah implode is so nice for that :) Updated answer to include the span now.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `implode('</span>, <span>', $vals)` instead? That way, each value is in a span tag. That's what the OP seems to be doing in the code in question... Just a thought. =)

Comment: <?php  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('services');
    foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo('<span>' . implode(', ', $mykey_values) . '</span>');
    } ?>

gives me: Redesign, Nyhedsbrev, Fotografi, DesignRedesign, Nyhedsbrev, Fotografi, DesignRedesign, Nyhedsbrev, Fotografi, DesignRedesign, Nyhedsbrev, Fotografi, 

desired output would be: Redesign, Nyhedsbrev, Fotografi

Comment: ah I got it - the foreach messed it up. This solved it  <?php  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('services');
    {
    echo('<span>' . implode(', ', $mykey_values) . '</span>');
    } ?>

Thanks a bunch - you guys rock

Comment: @Jeff Rupert: Yes indeed! Updated my answer :)

Comment: For the record, the fastest means of running this code would be: `echo '<span>' , implode('</span>, <span>', $mykey_values) , '</span>';` as the commas prevent PHP from performing unnecessary computation and the parenthesis are unnecessary.

Comment: This technique will print an empty `<span></span>` when the array has a count of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this... the first one I can think of is instead of using echo, concatenate all the results into a string, then remove the last `,` character.

Another way would be to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` and then iterate to the size of `$mykey_values` - 1 and then print the last one without a `,`. And I'm sure others will post other ways (maybe with real code too - my PHP is too rusty for me to risk a real code sample).

Comment: Every time this comes up people say to check for `len-1` and omit the final comma; am I the only person that checks for `0` and omits the first? It seems so much easier

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<span>" . implode(',</span><span>',$mykey_values) . "</span>;
```

Edit: BTW, you don't use the loop if you use this code.

Comment: This technique will print an empty `<span></span>` when the array has a count of zero.